# Flatten an array with objects that have nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

Many questions similar to this one like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036487/one-liner-to-flatten-nested-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179283/flatten-an-array-with-nested-objects), but both are hard for me to modify to my needs as the code in the answers is super concise.

I have an array with objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        someProp: "value of some prop",
        metaData: {
            metaId: 123
            uuid: "2348_4354_dfgg_r343"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        someProp: "value of some prop again",
        metaData: {
            metaId: 321
            uuid: "9897_3543_ergl_j435"
        }
    }
]
```

I need this to look like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        someProp: "value of some prop",
        metaId: 123
        uuid: "2348_4354_dfgg_r343"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        someProp: "value of some prop again",
        metaId: 321
        uuid: "9897_3543_ergl_j435"
    }
]
```

So the properties of the nested `metaData` object have to become part of the parent object in each item in the array. So far I've tried:

```
console.log(Object.assign(
    {}, 
    ...function _flatten(o) { 
        return [].concat(...Object.keys(o)
            .map(k => 
                typeof o[k] === 'object' ?
                    _flatten(o[k]) : 
                    ({[k]: o[k]})
            )
        );
    }(events)
));
```

However, this only gives me on flattened object, but my array has two at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could spread the nested obejct.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, someProp: "value of some prop", metaData: { metaId: 123, uuid: "2348_4354_dfgg_r343" } }, { id: 2, someProp: "value of some prop again", metaData: { metaId: 321, uuid: "9897_3543_ergl_j435" } }],
    result = data.map(({ metaData, ...o }) => ({ ...o, ...metaData }));        

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```